# Filtrar con 2 condiciones en tabla Matlab

Tags: condiciones, select, filtro, matlab

¿Como puedo filtrar o seleccionar datos de una tabla con 2 condiciones?. MATLAB

```
DamageEventNY = StateNY(StateNY.Event_Type == "Blizzard" & StateNY.Event_Type == "Strong Wind",:)
```

EL resultado que obtengo es:

```
DamageEventNY =

  0×24 empty table
```